# Why does my polynomial method work correctly in small arrays but wrong in bigger ones?

Tags: c, math, polynomials

```
double my_poly(double a[], double x, int degree){
   long int i;
   double result = a[0];
   double xpwr= 1/x;
   for(i=1; i<degree;i+=2){
      xpwr = x * x * xpwr;
      result = result + ((a[i] + (a[i+1] * x)) * xpwr); 
   }    
   return result;
}
```

The code above yields correct values for small-sized arrays. But when I use an array with a size 1000 the result comes wrong. Please, can you help me?

Edit:
I have examined as suggested;

```
double b[4] = {1,2,4,5};
printf("%f\n", poly(b,2,3));
printf("%f\n", my_poly(b,2,3));
```

Output:

```
61.000000
21.000000
```

According to the @Ian Abbott 's comment I have added this code block before the return statement, to satisfy both even and odd degrees:

```
for(; i<=degree;i++){
    xpwr = x * x * xpwr;
    result += a[i] * xpwr;   
 }
```

So the test outputs are consistent.

```
printf("%f\n", poly(a,2,999));
printf("%f\n", my_poly(a,2,999));
```

Yields:

```
61.000000
61.000000
```

Comment: Use `printf` to find where your anwers are going astray.

Comment: Does a simpler version that does one coefficient at a time work correctly? I can see that this version might have problems when `degree` is an even number.

Comment: Is the arrays size (which I think translates to the highest used power) the only influence? Or does is also take values>1 for the variable? If you try to calculate e.g. 100 to the power of 1000 and then don't get the correct result, then I would not exactly be surprised... Especially if "wrong" includes "only wrong in the decimal places".

Comment: Perhaps you could show a typical usage of this function for polynomials of small degree, preferably one with odd degree and one with even degree?

Comment: Calling your `poly` function with the `x` parameter set to 0 would result in a divide by zero error.

Comment: Thank you all. I have updated my question. If I do not have mistake it works now. Appreciated to your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding that code block before the return statement solved my problem.

```
for(; i<=degree;i++){
    xpwr = x * x * xpwr;
    result += a[i] * xpwr;   
 }
```